# AFNetworking for Image Downloads, Unresponsive UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, thread-safety, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to pull images from a URL, resize, store to disk and log the path in Core Data, then load to a table view and store .  When the code executes it freezes my UI. I'm not sure if it's the download or the manipulation that's causing my troubles.

The code I'm using is below

```
- (void)getPhoto:(NSInteger)type forManagedObject:(MyManagedObject*)object {

    // download the photo
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.photoUrl]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(UIImage *image) {


        // MyManagedObject has a custom setters (setPhoto:,setThumb:) that save the
        // images to disk and store the file path in the database 
        object.photo = image;
        object.thumb = [image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(PhotoBlockCellButtonWidth, PhotoBlockCellButtonHeight)];

        NSError *nerror;
        if (![[DataStore sharedDataStore].managedObjectContext save:&nerror]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [nerror localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // notify the table view to reload the table
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableView" object:nil];

    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

And here is a sample code relevant to the setter from my managed object

```
- (NSString*)uniquePath{

    // prepare the directory string
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // acquire a list of all files within the directory and loop creating a unique file name
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *existingFiles = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSString *uniquePath;
    do {
        CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        CFStringRef newUniqueIdString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);

        uniquePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:(__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIdString] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];

        CFRelease(newUniqueId);
        CFRelease(newUniqueIdString);
    } while ([existingFiles containsObject:uniquePath]);

    return uniquePath;
}

- (NSString*)saveImage:(UIImage*)image{
    NSString *path = [self uniquePath];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",path];
}

- (void) setPhoto:(UIImage *)image {
    self.photoUrl = [self saveImage:image];
}
```

I would like to push this to a background thread, but I'm not sure what the implications are with AFNetworking, Core Data, and Messaging in terms of thread safety. Any thought?

Comment: Two things: 1) Use the `AFImageRequestOperation` class method that takes the `imageProcessingBlock` parameter, and do the image resizing there. 2) I would recommend _against_ storing images (or any blobs of data, really) in Core Data; it's usually a better idea to store the image url and use `NSURLCache` or some other mechanism to load that as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Matt, moving my image processing code into the imageProcessingBlock helped. Love your networking class by the way.

Comment: `AFImageRequestOperation` uses its own thread, so executing `[operation start]` should *not* block the current thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Matt's suggestion, I improved the UI by reworking my call as follows.

```
- (void)getPhoto:(NSInteger)type forManagedObject:(MyManagedObject*)object {

    // download the photo
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.photoUrl]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation 
        imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
        imageProcessingBlock:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
            return [image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(PhotoBlockCellButtonWidth, PhotoBlockCellButtonHeight)];
        } 
        cacheName:nil 
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

            // MyManagedObject has a custom setters (setPhoto:,setThumb:) that save the
            // images to disk and store the file path in the database 
            object.photo = image;
            object.thumb = image;

            NSError *nerror;
            if (![[DataStore sharedDataStore].managedObjectContext save:&nerror]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [nerror localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            // notify the table view to reload the table
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableView" object:nil];                                                                 
        } 
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error getting photo");
        }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the way you are executing your request in incorrect:

```
[operation start];
```

you should instead add the operation to an `NSOperationQueue`:

```
    NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

(you should correctly memory-manage the queue).

By doing like this, your request will be executed in an async way, it won't block the UI and you will not need to deal with multithreading.

Comment: +1 I neglected to mention that I'm already calling getPhoto through an NSOperationQueue that I use to manage all of my server access in the background. Matt's solution helped.